# The system cannot find the file specified. (References .dll file)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have 2 Projects of ClassLibrary (solution A) and 1 Website Project (solution B),

e.g.

- Project1
- Project2
- WebProject

** (All Project target framework 4.7.1)

Project 2 add reference Project1.dll (used some functions from project1),
I tried to compiled the Project2 (Copy Local = false for project1.dll) 
and tried to add reference project2.dll to WebProject,
and running the webproject and got this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Project1.dll, Version=1.0.0.1,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.

can the webproject run without having the dll's of project1?
or how to hidden project1.dll from showing up in the bin folder of the webproject?

Comment: can the webproject run without having the dll's of project1? --> only you can know this. can it? if it needed, then don't.

how to hidden project1.dll from showing up in the bin folder of the webproject? --> why would you do this?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli hi leandro, in this case the webproject only used the functions from project2, and project1 functions only used in project2,  if the webproject not used any functions from project1 it still needed dll project1 in the webproject?

Comment: so you need everything and you can't hide it. Is like your stomach needs water, but your somatch need your mouth and your mouth need the glass.

Comment: If the web project uses functionality from project 2 and that functionality uses functionality from project 1, how could the web project work without the project 1 assembly?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli but my stomach just needs the water not need glass in there :D 
why do I need to hide project1, I have code like a serial key, etc in there, and I read in an article the DLL can be decompiled, so if I used many DLL's in project1 it will be showing everything I used in webproject.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I was thinking since project1 is already references in project2 so it doesn't need DLL project1 in webproject :)

Comment: For sure you want to secure your server before your dll, dll Is not public, Is only read by IIS

Comment: Do you think references are magic? You can't use functionality from a library without the library. The reference simply tells the project that the library exists and where to find it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am so sorry, I want to ask this, the project2 DLL included project1?
WebProject -> Project2 -> Project1, if webproject needs the library of project1 its available in project2 DLL (because project2 has referenced project1)? CMIIW

Comment: You've been told over and over that you need the project 1 DLL, the first time by the error message you posted yourself. Why would you be told that if one DLL magically contained another? DLLs are not hidden inside each other. If your app depends on a DLL that depends on another DLL, both DLLs must be present for your app to work. This is pretty basic programming knowledge that we shouldn't have to teach you here.

Comment: If your Web project does not use 1.DLL, there is no need to introduce 1.DLL in the Web project. Your project 2 refers to 1.DLL, but when converting project 2 to 2.DLL, it already contains the reference 1.DLL. The error you are getting should be that there was a problem converting 2.DLL. You can set the "Copy Local" property of the 1.dll reference in Project 2 to "True". How to hide 1.dll you asked is not related to this error, but I have given the answer below, you can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is ingenious. Usually if we introduce multiple DLLs, it will inevitably lead to redundant resource expenditures and the inconvenience of managing multiple DLLs. But unfortunately the web project cannot run without the project 1 DLL.

However, we can think about it in another way:

Solution 1: If the structures of your project 1 and project 2 are not so complicated, you can merge the two projects. Then generate a DLL.

Solution 2: Hiding the DLL

1. Generate a key

(1) Find Sn.exe, mine is Win10 64-bit, under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64;

(2) Open cmd, enter this directory, `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64`;

(3) Executing `sn -k keyfile.snk` in cmd will generate a key file in the current directory;

2. Sign the assembly

(1) Copy keyfile.snk to the directory of class library 1;

(2) Open the properties of 1, enter the generation, strong signature, check the assembly signature, select the strong name key file, and generate the class library;

[image]

(3) Add the assembly to the cache: execute `gacutil -i 1.dll` in cmd

(4) Modify reference properties: class library 2 adds a reference to class library 1, checks the properties of the reference, changes copy local to False, regenerates the class library, and there is only one 2.dll under the bin.